# tufte: cannot externalize more than 1 graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tufte, tikz-external

This seems to be strange combination of tufte-book and the graphing library. I am note able to externalize more than 1 graph and I cannot see why.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, external} 
\usegdlibrary{circular} 
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    \tikz{\graph{A};}
    \tikz{\graph{B};}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

- The full log is here: https://pastebin.com/sbqSVQgx
- tufte-lua-figure0.log: https://pastebin.com/uD1hgANe
- tufte-lua-figure1.log: https://pastebin.com/VVYVAXWZ

Package: tikz 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)

Edit:

I looked into [tufte-common.def](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/tufte-common.def) and the following line causes the error:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@letterspace}}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@pdf}\AND\boolean{@tufte@letterspace@pkg@prereqs}\AND\NOT\boolean{@tufte@xetex}}{%
    % load letterspace pkg
    \IfFileExists{letterspace.sty}{%
      \@tufte@letterspacing@letterspace
    }{}%
  }{}%
  % load soul pkg
  \@ifpackageloaded{letterspace}{}{%
    \IfFileExists{soul.sty}{%
      \@tufte@letterspacing@soul % <---- ERROR
    }{%
      \@tufte@warning@noline{Couldn't locate `soul' package}%
    }% soul not installed... giving up.
  }%
}{}

\newcommand{\@tufte@letterspacing@soul}{%
  \RequirePackage{soul}%
  \sodef\allcapsspacing{}{0.15em}{0.65em}{0.6em}%
  \sodef\smallcapsspacing{}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%
  \sodef\sotextsc{\scshape}{0.075em}{0.5em}{0.6em}%
  \renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\allcapsspacing{\MakeTextUppercase{##1}}}%
  \renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{##1}}}%
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\sotextsc{##1}} % <---- ERROR
}
```

Comment: It seems you are not using `pgfplots` so please replace it with `tikz`. And could you please add a bit more of the log. And please also add the version of `tikz` you are using. Thanks.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I updates the post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. And now please also add the log of the "externalized" image `tufte-lua-figure0.log`. Hopefully there we find the solution ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow I added the tufte-lua-figure0.log

Comment: I do not know anything about `tufte-book` but when I replace the document class by, say, `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` everything works as expected. One way to go might be to look at the section **Troubleshooting and Support** of the `tufte-book` manual and try to contact some experts of this class.

Comment: @godbyk can you please have a look at this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my post, the problem is somehow the line

```
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\sotextsc{##1}}
```

I do not know, why this only causes an error at `\tikzexternalize`. I also do not know if `letterspace` or `soul` should be used with lualatex, but a workaround is to just call letterspace again:

```
\makeatletter
\@tufte@letterspacing@letterspace
\makeatother
```